# Adjust size of absolute positioned divs based on height of heading tag for a responsive site

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a question regarding getting absolute positioned DIVs to adjust height based on the content contained within a heading tag. The design calls for color bars to expand outside of the contained area (1170px max), which is centered on screen.

I have the HTML/CSS figured out, but I figured I would need to use JQuery because the implementation is to be in WordPress, so there was a need to come up with a system that can find any h2 and h3 tags with the class ".bar" within the specified content div ".main" to then append the appropriate DIV tag setup to get the desired look.'

The issue is when the browser resizes. When the headings break into two lines, other than refreshing the site, the bar sizes no longer match up. I've tried a `$(window).on('resize', function(){`, but it keeps adding new divs and it gets goofed up.

Here's a more simplified example of the design

**HTML**

```
<div class="main">
<h2 class="bar">Even the all-powerful Pointing</h2>
<p>Has no control about the blind texts it is an almost unorthographic life One day     however a small line of blind text by the name of Lorem Ipsum     decided to leave for the far World of Grammar. The Big Oxmox advised her not to do so, because there were thousands of bad Commas, wild Question Marks and devious Semikoli, but the Little Blind Text didn’t listen.</p>
<h3 class="bar">She packed her seven versalia</h3>
<p>Put her initial into the belt and made herself on the way. When she reached the first hills of the Italic Mountains, she had a last view back on the skyline of her hometown Bookmarksgrove, the headline of Alphabet Village and the subline of her own road, the Line Lane. Pityful a rethoric question ran over her cheek, then she continued her way. On her way she met a copy.</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.gray-bar {
  background: #888f95;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 42.7%;
  height: 5px;
  z-index: -1;
}
.main h2.bar, .main h3.bar {
  background: #888f95;
  color: white;
  padding: .33em 0;
}
.main{
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$( ".main h2.bar" ).wrapAll( "<div class='section-head' />");
$( ".main h3.bar" ).wrapAll( "<div class='section-head' />");
$( ".main" ).find( ".section-head" ).prepend("<div class='gray-bar'></div>");
var heads = 0;
$( "div.section-head" ).each(function() {
    heads++;
    var foo = "foo"+heads;
    $( this ).addClass(foo);
    newHead = "."+foo;
    var z3 = $(newHead).height();
    $(newHead).children(".gray-bar").css("height", z3);
});
});
```

Here's a Fiddle of an example with my Javascript
http://jsfiddle.net/unwrittendevin/PB48u/

Answer (score 0):

I've put together a little "proof of concept" [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/cFqTq/3/) that will update the size of an absolutely positioned div whenever the window is scrolled. The size changes proportionately based on the height of another div.

You click on any of the blue boxes and the height of the whole div changes. The next time you scroll the window, the fixed div will change its size.

Is this generally what you're looking for?

JS

```
$('.variablediv').on('click', function(){
    $('.variablediv').css('height', '70px');
});

$( window ).scroll(function(){
    var heightcontainer = $('.container').height();
    var heightfixeddiv = +heightcontainer;
    $('.absolutediv').css( 'height', heightfixeddiv );
});
```

Comment: I was looking to see if there was a way to re-adjust the size of the absolute positioned div when the screen resizes smaller. It's noticeable when the h2 goes to a second line. 

I've gotten it to work with a resize event, but is there a better way to go about it? [http://jsfiddle.net/unwrittendevin/t4SMy/](http://jsfiddle.net/unwrittendevin/t4SMy/)

Comment: Ok, but I don't see the .on('resize'  in your js. Can you add that and perhaps be more detailed about the problem? It shouldn't "add" divs, just move them around on a resize.